# Run command line program from php file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, shell, command-line

I want to execute any command from php file. 
I have one nodejs file and when I give command to execute something. it works fine.
i.e. abc.js argument this works fine from terminal and execute some task

but, I want to execute same task from php file which runs my command.
I tried with exec('filename argument') that does not work. If I give exec(ls -l) that gives me output.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `shell_exec`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: I also did that and tried with absolute path of file but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use the node command to execute the js file try using

```
exec('/home/bin/node abc.js');
```

note use full paths like this /usr/bin/node /tmp/tmp.js or c:\nodejs\bin\node c:\proj\app.js

Comment: Ok..Let me check with this

Comment: Yes I tried with all.
I gave full path of node, js and arguments. but, Its not working.
exec('/usr/local/bin/node /path/abc.js argument');

Comment: It has to work. Can you try same command is working in command prompt or not?

Comment: just execute some node command and check the output like `exec('/usr/local/bin/node -v');`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66718/discussion-between-arun-kumar-and-rishabh-shah).

Comment: did u check the exits status here?